# R shiny tables changing headings and light dark mode switch

Tags: css, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am doing a basic visualisation for Covid-19 and in one of the tabs I have a table. I can't seem to get the writing above and below the table in another colour. I've included an image that highlights the writing that I need changed.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbcke.png]

I would also like to build a light and dark mode but I can't find any code that would work in the form I have the app now. My code with these issues is currently as follows

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

####################### READ CSV #############################
ncov <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/time-series-19-covid-combined.csv")
ncov = ncov %>% rename(Country = Country.Region)
###########################################################

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("slate"),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      "
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&display=swap');

h2 {
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    font-size: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
ul.nav li a {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

    #To change text and background color of the `Select` box 
    .dataTables_length select {
      color: #0E334A;
        background-color: #0E334A
    }

  ##To change text and background color of the `Search` box 
  .dataTables_filter input {
    color: #0E334A;
      background-color: #0E334A
  }

  thead {
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  tbody {
    color: #000000;
  }


"
    )
  ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",

                  tabPanel(title = "Table", icon = icon("table"),
                           tags$br(),
                           dataTableOutput("table"))
               )
             )
             )

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
   ncov %>%
      group_by(Country) %>%
      arrange(Country) %>%
      slice(1) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(Country)  
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please be sure to post a minimal and reproducible example. In this case you were missing a package dependency (`shinythemes`). You can make the code simpler by using a built in R table (like iris, or mtcars) and omitting any processing of the data frame which is irrelevant for your problem. Please check the `reprex` package and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more info on minimal examples.

Comment: Also, regarding `renderDataTable` and `dataTableOutput`. These functions are exported by both `shiny` and `DT` packages, although the `renderDT/DToutput` aliases are from the `DT` package. To avoid mistakes, be explicit when calling these functions with `DT::renderDT` or `shiny::renderDataTable`. In general, the `DT` versions are to be preferred, because I believe the `shiny` versions of these functions will be deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This CSS should get you some or most of the way there.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("slate"),
                tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
                  "
                  .dataTables_length label,
                  .dataTables_filter label,
                  .dataTables_info {
                      color: white!important;
                      }

                  .paginate_button {
                      background: white!important;
                  }

                  thead {
                      color: white;
                      }

                  "))),
                mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                  type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel(
                    title = "Table",
                    icon = icon("table"),
                    tags$br(),
                    DT::DTOutput("table")
                  )
                )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    iris
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I'll include your other suggestions for future posts. How would I put the colours and themes on a switch so I can make a light/dark mode switch?

Comment: You'll probably need to define a second CSS class for the dark mode, and develop some JavaScript logic to turn it on and off. This can be done with the `shinyjs` package (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shinyJS+add+remove+class) or directly with JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks I got it working. I also see now that the way to check what code to use to change specific elements in the table is to use the inspect element function. One thing I can't figure out though is how to change the writing in the Show Entries dropdown in the top left to black without changing the Show entries writing as well. In the Inspect element it seems like it's all referred to by the same class.

Comment: After poking around a bit, this seems to work: `button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {color: red!important}`. But I'm not a CSS expert by any stretch, so there might be a better or more correct way of doing this..

Comment: Thanks. Someone showed me now that the best way to change it would be .dataTables_length label select {color: black; }